# Characteristic of $\overline{\mathbb F_2}$

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields

I have a very basic algebraic question in mind. I am not an algebraist, but this question naturally pops up in my work. Given a field, which consists of two elements $\mathbb F_2$, and its algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb F_2}$, what is the $char(\overline{\mathbb F_2})$? Is it $2$?

Comment: Yes it is. Characteristic does not change when you extend the field, since the equality $1+1+\ldots+1=0$ does not depend on what you added to the field